# Is "lynch" considered a racist word?

Tags: terminology, connotation, racism

Let's say that for example, people thought Chris was a bad person and he killed many people. A group of people vote for Chris to be lynched. Race has absolutely nothing to do with this; it's because of Chris's actions. This is the context for the use in question of the word "lynch".

My friend says the term "lynch" is such a racially-loaded term that we should use the word "hanging" instead. He says that the word "lynch" carries specific connotations of racist violence.

Please English experts tell me your insight on this! Is it ***actually*** racist or is he going overboard?

Comment: It is possible to be hung without being lynched. It is possible to be lynched without being hung. You can't blindly replace *lynch* with *hang*, they're not synonymous. And the word is pejorative but not racist.

Comment: "lynch" means to execute without a trial.  The word has racial connotations because there is a history in the U.S. of black people being lynched by racist groups like the KKK.

Comment: The word is not racist, but people who lynch other people could be. But to lynch someone does necessarily mean to hang them.

Comment: Let's say that for example, people thought Chris was a bad person and he killed many people. A group of people vote for Chris to be lynched. So in this case, chris was lynched. This is the context "lynch" is being used as. Nothing racist I see, what do you think?

Comment: Correct. Race has absolutely nothing to do with this. It's because of Chris's actions.

Comment: Yes he flat out called it racist for some reason. Because of its origins. But how is that true at all? I just proved him wrong with the example i gave. It depends on the context, so it's not racist at all times.

Comment: If 'racist' means 'carrying connotations of racist violence', it only takes one person to pick up on this nuance to make the term 'racist'. Connotations are subjective. The snag is that there's probably a person somewhere who thinks that 'blackmail' or 'Blackpool' carry racist overtones, and the language becomes in danger of being hijacked by over-sensitive minorities.

Comment: I would echo @RaceYouAnytime 's comment that lynching conveys "without a trial" . It is can also used metaphorically for a vocal group attack blocking an action through character assassination or alleged underhanded and virulently angry mob means.  The 'Angry Mob'  is a critical part.  A panel that deliberated and votes might be violating civil rights etc.. but it's less a lynching than a fixed trial .

Comment: In american history, the term "high tech lynching" casts some modern color on the use of the word.  During his confirmation hearings a number of women, most particularly Anita Hill testified that he had made sexual advances of a continuous nature which she and many others believed rose to the level of sexual harassment.  The hearings began to spin out of control with even records of Justice Thomas's video tape rentals surfacing. When Thomas testified about Hill's claims before the Senate Judiciary Committee, he called the hearings, "a high-tech lynching for uppity Blacks."

Comment: @DanBron Greetings. I fear a lynch mob might well chase me off this site if I didn't point out that pictures are "hung", but never humans, who are merely hanged. "Hung" with regard to the male of the species has an entirely different meaning quite unconnected to being strung up or placed over the trapdoor leading to the "drop". Bit of gallows humor, what?

Comment: I don't think most people nowadays would want to call any actions of their own a *lynching*, as it is clearly the action of villains, regardless of whether they are motivated by racism or some other extrajudicial animus.

Comment: @1006a: People can make overstatements. _"If he calls me "boy" one more time, I'm lynching him on the spot"_ (meaning that you'll take offence to his statement regardless of whether he meant to patronise you or not). It doesn't need to be factually correct for it to be said.

Comment: @PeterPoint - Well, on this site we have both descriptivists and prescriptivists; I doubt all of the former would object to a person being hung (in the sense of killed).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "the language becomes in danger of being hijacked" I think you're being a bit extreme in your word choice here especially considering "minorities" have no less input on the English language than anyone else.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai But surely minorities having the same input as majorities is disproportionate: the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I mean on the individual level; a speaker of English who is a member of a minority group has no less influence than anyone else.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I believe that there are certain terms that have already been hijacked by minorities. And there are few who wouldn't agree that the drive for political correctness has reached ridiculous extremes.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai  Over 100 000 Google hits for "political correctness gone mad".  And you can check for actual examples among the 170 000 Google hits for "hijacked the word". Oh, and I've flagged your previous comment as being a personal attack.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And there's more than 645,000 results for "vaccines cause autism," so I'm not sure what your point is. That wasn't even the part of your comment I was addressing. And go ahead: I called your remarks awful, not you.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Then which part of the comment do you find awful? Notice that I'm using 'minorities' in the first sense (and therefore that which should be taken as the default reading defined by say CED) (smaller groupings than 50%): 'The snag is that there's probably a person somewhere who thinks that 'blackmail' or 'Blackpool' carry racist overtones, and [if they gather a following – undesirable groups often arise] the language becomes in danger of being hijacked by over-sensitive minorities.' ...

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-racist-every-time-we-use-a-color-word-to-mean-something-other-than-color) has an article showing that the issue has certainly raised concerns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The comment I called awful was the one that began "I believe..." You're calling innovations and usages driven by minorities "hijacking," as if the way you want English to go is "the right way" or that certain groups not be allowed to use English the way they seem fit. Your initial use of "oversensitive minorities" and your "blackmail" strawman seemed quite bigoted because we were discussing racially charged terms. Calling it the "default reading" doesn't matter. ... Also, that Quora "article" is worth nothing.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Please don't misquote. The example of a minority I clearly provided was in "The snag is that there's probably a person somewhere who thinks that 'blackmail' or 'Blackpool' carry racist overtones." I'm saying that there have been _some_ hijackings by _some_ minority groups. (These include meteorologists insisting that a certain definition of 'hurricane' is the only correct one, and scientists insisting that 'sulphur' is a misspelling.) ...

Comment: There are some people who equate 'minority' with 'should be treated better than the majority' and 'almost bound to be right'. ...'that Quora "article" is worth nothing' is an arrogation par excellence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't misquote anything. "*There are some people who equate 'minority' with 'should be treated better than the majority' and 'almost bound to be right*'" I don't even know what you're talking about anymore. --- And calling my comment an "arrogation par excellence" is highly ironic coming from the guy who calls opinions on English he doesn't like "hijackings." Find someone else to take your frustrations out on.

Comment: @AndyT  Prof. Higgins who said of Eliza Doolittle: "Look at her, a prisoner of the gutter; condemned by every syllable she utters; by right she should be taken out and HUNG; for the cold-blooded muder of the English tongue". Quite so! With apologies to George Bernrad Shaw, Alan Jay Lerner & the English language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Lynch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lynch)** by definition means someone was put to death without a legal process. It usually refers to death by hanging, but not necessarily.

**[Hang](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang)** means hang to death by rope, legally or otherwise.

The word "lynch" in the U.S. is often associated with a history of extrajudicial killing of black people, usually by racist organizations like the Ku Klux Klan.

Whether the term "lynch" would be considered racist would depend on the context in which it was used.
If the term was referring to a black individual in the U.S., it might be perceived as racially or historically insensitive.

See the Wikipedia page on [Lynching in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynching_in_the_United_States) for more information.

Comment: _"Whether the term "lynch" on its own would be considered racist would depend on the context in which it's used."_ "on its own" and "the context" contradict each other. A word on its own is inherently evaluated without a surrouding context. That's what "on its own" **means**. Words (without context) are not defined by a single possible underlying contextual motivation. Smashing a storefront is not inherently robbery, buying a gun is not inherently murder, having sex with someone is not inherently rape, lynching is not inherently racist.

Comment: I would say that it is racially charged, or racially sensitive, but not itself racist.  For example, in an work environment, one might use "lynched" to mean "severely punished, or fired", eg *"Steve's going to want to have you lynched if he finds out about this"*. One might feel uneasy to use the term if the subject was African-American, because of the history of the word with that community - it brings up a lot of unpleasant history.  Therefore it does have a "racial" element.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I would refrain from telling my hypocritical boss that he "talks the talk but cannot walk the walk" if my boss is bound to a wheelchair; but that does not mean that the saying has an inherent connotation of discriminating against the handicapped. Avoiding an ambiguity does not imply that the two meanings overlap in any way.

Comment: @Flater that's an excellent analogy.  That's why I say that the word isn't itself racist but it is "racially charged or "racially sensitive".  In the OP's words his friend said it was "racially loaded" (the same thing) and I think the friend is right.  I think the OP has confused things by saying "My friend says it's racially loaded" and then saying "Is it actually racist?" (a different thing).

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I get your point, but I think the issue lies with "racially loaded". "Racially loaded" speaks to something that is inherent to the statement, rather than someone's wrong inference. (see also: "loaded question"). This doesn't need to be intentional by the speaker, but it does need to be _inherent to the statement_, which is not the case here. I think it's more accurate to say that "lynching" **isn't** racially loaded, but that it **could be (wrongly) inferred** as such.

Comment: @Flater thanks for pointing out that paradoxical wording. Edit made for posterity.

Comment: @Flater, possibly, though we're now arguing whether "loaded" has to mean "deliberately loaded".  I think that's going off on a bit of a tangent.  Really, the pragmatic answer to the question is "Yes, the word lynch has some some racial connotations which you need to bear in mind, and decide whether you want to risk offending someone".

Comment: @MaxWilliams: If we're arguing whether a statement is racially loaded or not, it is very much on topic to make sure we agree on the definition of "racially loaded". That is not a tangent, it's quintessential to considering whether that friend's statement is correct. Also notice that I didn't argue intent (a loaded question can be asked without the intention of making it a loaded question). "Yes, the word lynch has some some racial connotations" The **act** of lynching people in the context of American history, yes. The **word** "lynching" by itself in the English language, no.

Comment: @MaxWilliams:To prove the point: the word "genocide", when said in the context of German history, has clear connotations to the Holocaust and antisemitism. But that does not mean that "genocide" inherently refers to _killing the Jewish_. "Genocide" is not an antisemitic word in and of itself, even if genocide has been committed in an antisemitic context in the past. Similarly, lynching is not inherently racist, even if lynching has occurred in a racist context in the past. I'm not saying that the OP shouldn't avoid sensitive topics, but **a connotation is not the same as an inherent meaning**.

Answer (score 5):

I would object on two points: one, the word *lynch* is not "racist" but rather "racially charged"; two, it's not a matter of its origins but of its later associations.  I would still probably avoid the word - but to avoid dragging in confusing associations, rather than for fear of causing offence.

As has been pointed out by WS2, the term "lynch law" pre-dates the KKK, and the earliest victims were not black.  That being said, the KKK and its actions have hijacked the popular conception of the terms, so when you use the word "lynch" most people will not think of "rough vigilante justice, followed by summary execution", but of "white-on-black murder".  For most audiences in the early 21st century, this is likely to result in a good deal of sympathy for the person being lynched.  If that was not your intent, you should use a different phrase.

There is also an unfortunate tendency for people, undergoing some criticism or societal disapproval, to compare themselves to victims of much greater historical injustices - think of [Godwin's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law), for example.  Throwing around the term "lynching" too loosely - "I'm getting lynched here" - should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

It undoubtedly has historic and cultural connections to race, ***but I do not believe it is offensively racist***.

The term ***lynch*** refers to what was known as ***Lynch law*** - described by the OED as:

> The practice of inflicting summary punishment upon an offender, by a
>   self-constituted court armed with no legal authority; it is now
>   limited to the summary execution of one charged with some flagrant
>   offence.

It is undoubtedly true that the vast majority of victims of lynch law were black. So the term *lynch* has racial connotations but **I do not see why it should be considered offensively racist, or why it cannot equally be applied to a white victim of such**.

A victim of Lynch Law, moreover, is not necessarily hanged nor, historically, even killed. The term is meant to cover any form of extra-judicial punishment, though I have never heard it used for anything other than hangings (or perhaps strangulations).

The OED is unsure about the etymology of *lynch law*, but proposes the following:

> ‘The origin of the expression has not been determined. It is often
>   asserted to have arisen from the proceedings of Charles Lynch, a
>   justice of the peace in Virginia, who in 1782 was indemnified by an
>   act of the Virginia Assembly for having illegally fined and imprisoned
>   certain Tories in 1780. But Mr. Albert Matthews informs us that no
>   evidence has been adduced to show that Charles Lynch was ever
>   concerned in acts such as those which from 1817 onward were designated
>   as “Lynch's law”. It is possible that the perpetrators of these acts
>   may have claimed that in the infliction of punishments not sanctioned
>   by the laws of the country they were following the example of Lynch,
>   which had been justified by the act of indemnity; or there may have
>   been some other man of this name who was a ring-leader in such
>   proceedings. Some have conjectured that the term is derived from the
>   name of Lynche's Creek, in South Carolina, which is known to have been
>   in 1768 a meeting-place of the “Regulators”, a band of men whose
>   professed object was to supply the want of regular administration of
>   criminal justice in the Carolinas, and who committed many acts of
>   violence on those suspected of “Toryism”.’ (N.E.D.)   The particulars
>   supplied by Ellicott, together with other evidence, clearly establish
>   the fact that the originator of Lynch law was Captain William Lynch
>   (1742–1820) of Pittsylvania in Virginia. According to Ellicott, ‘this
>   self-created judicial tribunal was first organized in the state of
>   Virginia about the year 1776’; an article in the Southern Lit.
>   Messenger (1836) 2 389 gives the date definitely as 1780.

Comment: There are some well-documented cases of extrajudicial killings not by hanging in the same context as most US lynchings and described by the same word. I can't honestly recommend reading about them.

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks for the warning. Notwithstanding a passion for history, I am not a person who takes much delight in reflecting on such things.

Answer (score -1):

The question is not the word itself, The real question is where the word first appeared in history and for what reasons that word was used for. Was the word used universally or for a specfic group of people? In www.vocabulary.com it says the word comes from a persons action that occured during a racialially motivated time. "When people take the law into their own hands and decide to punish a suspected criminal — or merely a person who's seen as challenging the status quo — the result can unfortunately be a lynching. Lynchings have most often involved hanging, especially during the period of racially motivated lynchings in the American South. The word lynching and its related verb, lynch, come from Captain William Lynch, who took control of imposing and policing order in Virginia during the Revolutionary War."  In www.Wikipedia.com it says the word lynching came out in 1720 in a document that lynch claimed to be the author that later was declared a hoax by experts, apparently the word lynching was written by a racist authors in the 1970's for whatever reasons they had eventually became a word in the dictionary. So the word Lynching is actually a racist word, the word itself is by an author in the 1970's and all he did was create a divide between minorities and white people. So anyone sporting the name Lynch should not use it! If any person uses this word as a team name in any way then they are supporting racism, hundreads of slaves suffered or died under William Lynch. If a person uses this word in a loosely way then obviously they are ignorant to the definition of that word and where it came from, If you use this word and try to change it's meaning; he or she are not the originator of the word and are plagiarizing its definition if they are trying to change it, just go make up a word support it and build it!

Comment: This answer is well below the quality expected here.